# Can i Send mail using other Hosting SMTP?

Tags: laravel, email, smtp

I have a client that has hosting, let's call it `abc.com`, that has `Laravel` installed on it. Long story short, I tried configuring `smtp` from hosting and always had an error. After I tried using `smtp` gmail it worked. So, my client wants to try another hosting, let's call it `def.com`.

The question is can `abc.com` use smtp from `def.com`?

Comment: Yes, but `def.com` may need specific configuration to send mail on behalf of `abc.com` (both at the SMTP server level, and in DNS via a SPF/DKIM record set).

Comment: i never dig that deeper before. can you tell me what thi logs cause ? 503-\"Your IP: 198.xxx.xx.xx4 : Your domain sfosecureform.claims is not allowed

Comment: That means your `def.com` SMTP server is (correctly) rejecting your attempts to send an email with a `From` domain it doesn't recognize. You would need to configure `def.com`'s SMTP server appropriately. It'll probaly be easier to engage an email service provider like Sendgrid or Amazon SES for this.